# Compiler run-time error reporting with location of error

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, runtime

I'm writing a compiler in C++ (Ubuntu 12.04. with gcc). So far, cumulative error/warning reporting with fairly precise line and column number of error/warning location works fine.

My project goals include simply learning how to do this, so I'm adding a preprocessing stage (in a first step doing only minimal stuff like string concatenation, comment removal, etc), creating a resulting tmp file. It will not be necessary at this point as I could concatenate strings in my lexer while parsing, and the lexer already handles comments fine, but I'd like to understand how to handle it efficiently and as elegantly as I can.

Compile time errors are not hard:   
    (1) do error check (-> report compile-time errors)
    (2) if no errors, preprocess -> tmp file
    (3) run parser, etc., on tmp file (which is compile-time error free)

However, I also report run-time errors with line number (eg, for array out of bounds checks for arrays with integer expression bounds). As the error checks will be added to the byte code of my IR when parsing the tmp file only, and this file can significantly differ from the source file (in particular if we start allowing the pasting in of header files, say), how on earth can you reasonably report helpful error location? Is there a standard trick how gcc, say, handles this? The type of bound check mentioned of course doesn't happen for C; but runtime error reporting applies to, say, dynamic resolution of pointers in a hierarchy in C++, and gcc gets the line numbers just fine.

Comment: You can check for errors in the tmp file, and - in case you find some - save the particular line, and search the main file for it.

Comment: @PawelStawarz: not a bad suggestion, but quite involved...involving quite a bit of re-factoring of my current error handling )(which, of course, might happen anyway :)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can record line number information in your temporary file produced by your preprocessor, such as [Line Control](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Line-Control.html#Line-Control) of `cpp`.

> The C preprocessor informs the C compiler of the location in your source code where each token came from. Presently, this is just the file name and line number.